# How do I create relationships and associations for a User Model of Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, relational-database

I am using devise for my user model and in the routes.rb I have `devise_for :users`
How would I go about giving users posts?

Would it just be in the routes:

```
resources :users do
    resources :posts
end
```

Or do you have to do something special due to devise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those routes will work, additionally you need to set up your relationships in your models, assuming your posts table includes user_id as a foreign key:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**edit**

To add the foreign key to your Post model:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_posts user_id:integer
```

This will create a migration file in the db/migrate folder that looks like:

```
class AddUserIdToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :posts, :user_id, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :posts, :user_id
  end
end
```

You can then migrate these changes to your database using:
    rake db:migrate

Comment: How do you add the user_id as foreign key?

Comment: @Planetpluto: see my edit.  This will allow you to use methods such as user.posts and post.user

Comment: And I can also do the exact smae for comments, right?
But replace post with comment

Comment: If comments are related to a post and a user then you need a has_many and belongs_to for both of those models, see my edits for the Model structure.  You need to include 2 foreign keys in your comments.

Comment: under the Post class, I think you meant : has_many :comments...not has_many :posts (as you have it)

Comment: @berto77 You are right. I have updated my answer to reflect this.